# How to initiate Min/Max loops with scanner

Tags: java, for-loop, initialization, max, min

In this problem, I need to ask the user to input the number of integers they will put in. Then, they will manually input each number. Finally, the program counts the sum and max of all even inputs.

I am having trouble with initiating the value. If I set them to zero, there would be an issue if all the numbers were negative even numbers.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Exercise07 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner thing = new Scanner(System.in);
    evenSumMax(thing);
}

private static void evenSumMax(Scanner stuff) {
    System.out.print("How many integers?");
    int times = stuff.nextInt();

    int evenSum = 0;
    int evenMax = 0;

    System.out.println("Number 1 : ");
    int value = stuff.nextInt();

    if (value % 2 == 0) {
        evenSum += value;
        evenMax = value;
    }

    for (int i = 2 ; i <= times; i++) {
        System.out.print("Number " + i + " : ");
        value = stuff.nextInt();

        if (value % 2 == 0) { // if even
            evenSum += value;
            if (evenMax < value) {
                evenMax = value;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Even sum = " + evenSum + ", even max = " + evenMax);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set evenMax to the minimum possible number [Integer.MIN_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)